# How to copy and append strings in 2-line chunks using perl

Tags: perl

```
while ($line = <IN>){
    ...
print OUT "$line";
print OUT1 "$line";
}
```

As far as I know my `while` loop only reads from my input file one line at a time. How can I adjust this so that it reads 2 lines at a time?

Suppose a 2-line chunk looks like this

```
%line1
THISISLINE2
```

I want my `while` loop to copy the first line and paste it after the second line (but replace % with @). I also want to add a line of 11 characters of `A` as line 4. Essentially I want the output to be

```
 %line1
 THISISLINE2
 @line1
 AAAAAAAAAAA
```

How can I write a `while` loop to do this?

Comment: You can call `$line = <IN>` inside your while loop to get the next line.

Comment: did you check [this article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=43603)?

Comment: As an alternative to reading double lines, you could perhaps use `%` as a record separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to make a guess that you've got multi-line records like this:

```
%line1
something something line1
%lineB 
something to do with lineb
```

I would suggest in this scenario - rather than reading two lines at a time, you instead set your record separator via `$/`.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "%";

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @lines = split "\n";
    next unless @lines;
    print '%', join( "\n", @lines ), "\n";
    print $lines[0] =~ s/^/\@/r, "\n";
    print "Something else to do with record $.\n";
    print "---END---\n";
}

__DATA__
%line1
something something line1
%lineB 
something to do with lineb
```

This means that each iteration of the while loop - it reads until the next `%` symbol. As a result, the first iteration is empty, but subsequent records will work fine.

This prints:

```
%line1
something something line1
@line1
Something else to do with record 2
---END---
%lineB 
something to do with lineb
@lineB 
Something else to do with record 3
---END---
```

Comment: Nice answer. Then  i had one doubt in your answer. Why used `local` for input record separator?  Without using `local` it gives output? I saw the many documentary about input record separator but it also have `local` infront of the record separator. What is actual need?

Comment: `$/` is a global, so changing it can have really odd consequences in non trivial code. `local` limits the scope of that change. In this example, it's irrelevant - but it is a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option for a loop that gets two lines at once:

```
my $l1;
my $l2;
while (defined($l1=<DATA>) and defined($l2=<DATA>))
{
    print "line 1: $l1\n";
    print "line 2: $l2\n";
}

__DATA__
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

This does not require reading the whole file into an array first.

It also ignores a single line at the end of the file (but you could change that by switching to `or`).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $fh, "<", "test.txt") or die $!;
open (my $op, ">", "output.txt") or die $!;

my @slurp = <$fh>;

while(my @lines = splice(@slurp, 0, 2)){
    my ($line1, $line2) = @lines;   
    print $op $line1;
    print $op $line2;
    if($line1 =~ s/%/@/){
        print $op $line1;           
        if($line2 =~ tr/.*/A/c){
            print $op $line2."\n";
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use a `for` loop instead of `while`? remember that `for` requires the whole file to be read into memory. but unless you have very high performance standards and a very big datafile it shouldn't a problem.

```
open IN,"<",$file;
my @lines = <IN>;
for (my $i = 0;$i le $#lines; $i = $i+2) {
    my $first_line = $lines[$i];
    my $second_line = $lines[$i+1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like a possible use case for a simple [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $state = 1;
my $first_line;

while (<>) {
    if ($state == 1) {
         $first_line = $_;
         $state = 2;
    } elsif ($state == 2) {
         # do whatever you want with $_ and $first_line
         $state = 1;
    } else {
         die "Unknown state '$state', not sure how we got here";
    };
};
```